# Which php framework would support restful API and NoSQL

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

Which PHP framework closely supports the following :

1. API (RESTful)
2. Nosql (mongodb / CouchDB etc)
3. Testing like Rspec in rails
4. AJAX Support

I want to create a mass email service. So I need an API, so clients can make new application for their specific needs.

Comment: And a new round of buzzword bingo has been opened! Beside: Just lookup frameworks in google and check if their feature list fullfills your requirements.

Comment: A PHP framework that supports AJAX? That's like saying I want a car that supports roads.

Comment: Well my wordings might have mislead you. By ajax support I mean, use of unobtrusive javascript as in ROR to be painless and elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First two bullet-points will be supported by Lithium ( pretty good frameworks, well commented, less-than-average magic , only minor structural/design issues compared to others ). For testing : as mentioned above - PhpUnit. Though there might be some issues with isolation of units ( then again , you come from RoR, so that will nothing new to you ).

And yes , "ajax support" is just a sign of how poor your web-development skill are. Especially because "AJAX" is a term used by marketing department. Developers call it XHR.

#### Followup 8 years later

Currently the whole premise of this question would be wrong. The professional community in PHP has left the "use frameworks" mindset and focuses on assembling the project's dependencies from Composer in form of libraries.

The rapid prototyping frameworks (like Laravel and Yii) are only uses in coal mines of "web agencies", that make sites without consideration for maintenance.

Answer (score -1):

Glue is probably one of the easiest/fastest ways of getting web service endpoints set up. phpUnit is for unit testing, NoSQL? Well, chances are you don't need it so it doesn't really matter anyways. AJAX support? Meaning what exactly?

Comment: No, they probably asked about NoSQL because they do need it, like I did and came across this question.